# Linear span of a compact set

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, compactness, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

Is the linear span of a compact set in $L^2(X)$ complete?

More specifically, let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space, and $E$ be a compact subset in $(L^2(X), ||.||_2)$. Then can we conclude that linear span of $E$, i.e,  $span(E)$ is a Banach space?

My intuition says yes, but having difficulties in proving it.

Comment: Look at $\{ e_n/n : n\in\Bbb N\}\cup\{0\}$ in $\ell_2$

Comment: You are right, thanks a lot !